# Not able to see chat through chat link

Tags: bug, status-norepro, chat

In some question I see that comments are moved to a chat and a link is provided for viewing the same. But my problem is whenever i try to open that link it shows me a window saying chat is opening but it never opens. Can somebody please let me know the reason. An example will be a chat link provided under [this topic](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3862/why-does-hinduism-has-so-many-gods/3877?noredirect=1#comment8807_3877)

Comment: What browsers(s) did you use, what operating system(s), etc.?  That may help others to diagnose your problem.

Comment: I am using Firefox 4.0.1 on Windows 7

Comment: Why don't you try other browsers to see if the problem persists?

Comment: I tried on chrome as well but the problem was still there.

Comment: Do you have any addons? Especially something like adblock or noscript?

Comment: Works for me and so should for you, also your Firefox is wayyyyyy toooo old, current version is 33.0 so consider upgrading your browsers.

Comment: I get it checked now. There was some firewall problem at my workplace which was stopping the page to appear. Things are Ok now. This question can be closed now. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Use norepro and not completed.